# Does my signal output need auditory processing to be audible?

Tags: python, audio, wav

I made a Variational Autoencoder (VAE) that takes in music and outputs music. According the my losses on training and plotting the timeseries it looks like it is doing an OK job. The problem is when I try to listen to it. I simply take my VAE model output and save it as a .WAV file. The problem is that when I listen, it sounds like a single tone beep despite the plot of the timeseries looking very similar to the original song. Below is code snippet and image example of a time series at 20KHz sampling rate and 4 minute length (4,800,000 samples).

```
import soundfile as sf 
sf.write('/content/sample_data/example7.wav', y, 20000)
```

[image]

My question is whether I should worry about my model or if my signal is missing a step in transformation to make it audible as a .WAV file.

Comment: What is the `dtype` of `y`? Can you share the data as a numpy array?

Comment: @LukaszTracewski It is a float 32 from a numpy array. I can share a preview of it here.
array([[-1.8463370e-04],
       [-3.1578584e-05],
       [-4.4440772e-04],
       ...,
       [ 6.2357337e-04],
       [-7.0134737e-04],
       [ 2.9425664e-04]], dtype=float32)